# Altium Outjob Custom Parameters

Tags: altium

I started using Altium Outjobs to generate assembly files.  Great change, should have done it sooner.

I understand how to use the custom parameters in the Outjob file; however, I've only found that you can link to the parameters in the Project Options.

Are there any other places where you can define parameters, that feed back to the Outjob?

I was orignally hoping you could update the board version (rev #) in the .SchDoc, so as you update the schematic the revision number changes.   I am using SVN for version control, so it is a little wonky updating the Project Parameters.

Comment: You typically don't revision schematic by page anyway, so you need a unified place to record the schematic version. I keep schematic revision, PCB revision, and assembly revision all in project properties.

Comment: You know what I don't like though?  And maybe I'm wrong.  

If you revert a commit, is the project file reverted back as well?  

I'm not certain if the project file gets committed in Altium's SVN approach.

Comment: You need to revert the whole project back to the same check-in revision, yeah, of course. Otherwise your files will be completely out of whack.

Answer (score 1):

You can define parameters per Variant as well. I define things like the PCB Number and PCB Revision in the Project Options -> Parameter page, in addition to my contact information, e-mails, etc. This stays static for the given PCB project, and I have a post-processing Python script that can pull out this information to auto-generate documentation.

For the assembled PCBs, i.e., populated with parts, I define different variants, and for each I can define a unique part number, revision, and anything else. These parameters can then be referenced on the schematic, and will be evaluated during OutJob export (i.e. spitting out PDFs).

In the OutJob itself, you can reference parameters while naming the files, which could be helpful to you. For SVN revisions, there might be a Special String field like `.VersionControl_ProjFolderRevNumber` or `.VersionControl_RevNumber`, but I think this depends on having Altium's built-in SVN working. And as of the latest version, IIRC, there's not an easy to point to an external SVN binary (like TortoiseSVN), so you could be SOL if you are using SVN+SSH or similar.